# Publishing with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compilation

When I publish my website with visual studio it deletes my image folder. I stroe uploaded pictures in that folder.

How can I stop visual studio from deleting stuff? should I use copy website option? When I use copy website opion does asp.net server compile the website automatically? Will my website work if I don't compile it before uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Any folders you want to be published must also be included in the project in Visual Studio, if it only exists on disk then it won't be published.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your images in the App_Theme folder, then may be it will not be deleted.
2. I don't think, Copy web site tool performs compilation. But before using it you should first buid your site.
3. Yes, it will work, if there is no error in your site.